# Is it possible in a static method to call another static method via Parallel.For with different parameters?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I need to accomplish something like (and they have told me explain more with lots of words...)

```
static MyReturnObject Function1(myObjectA parameter1, myObjectB parameter2) {...}

static void Test()
{
   Parallel.For( 0, 10, (index) =>
   {
     //create parameters y and z 
     x = Function1(y,z); 
     // Add x to an array
   });
   // Find the biggest x.
}
```

Code works but the result is not accurate. If i use "for" instead of "parallel.for", i get accurate result.

Comment: Did you run it and how compiler say?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but Parallel.For(...) is probably not the best solution (unless there is a specific requirement to use Parallel.For); I'd more likely use Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel().Select(...) instead.

Comment: i did run it. compiler does not give any warning or error. but the result is not accurate.

Comment: As long as Function1 isn't touching any shared data (class level statics etc) then you'll be fine. If it is then you'll need to think about synchronization of data.

Comment: actually, Function1 is using class level variables. i create a copy of those in parallel.for and use them in Function1.

Comment: `//Add x to an array` could be interesting. How do you make that thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried executing the code as per your rules and I am sure that it is possible to do the same.

Please find below code which I executed in an Winform application.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Test();
        }

        static int Function1(int parameter1, int parameter2)
        {
            return (parameter1 + parameter2);
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
            long total = 0;

            // Use type parameter to make subtotal a long, not an int
            Parallel.For<long>(0, nums.Length, () => 0, (j, loop, subtotal) =>
            {
                subtotal += (nums[j] + Function1(1,2));
                return subtotal;
            },
                (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x)
            );

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The total is {0}", total));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have changed my class from static, the problem repeats. It seems my Function1 is the problem.

Comment: I have chosen this answer because it answers the question, even though it does not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible in a static method to call another static method?*
Of course!

*Via Parallel.For?*
Why not?

*With different parameters?*
Not sure I understand what you mean here.  Do you wish instantiate new objects and pass them into your Function1 for each iteration of your Parallel.For?  Of course you can!

Comment: sure :) Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, see the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nUsing Parallel.For \n");

    Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, thread = {1}", i, Function1());
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int Function1()
{
    return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 
}
```